# Как открыть новую активность или фрагмент по нажатию на маркер?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api, google-maps

Работаю с Google maps API в Android Studio. Возник вопрос:как открыть новую активность или фрагмент по нажатию на маркер? Как я понял, Info Windows мне не подходит, Info Windows является статическим View, отображаемым в виде изображения на карте, а мне требуется, чтобы пользователь мог взаимодействовать с этим окном, нажимая на кнопки. В программирование новичок, буду рад любой помощи в этом вопросе.
Работаю во фрагменте, пробовал сделать так:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(name));
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getChildFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.info_fr, new InfoFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });
```

Но в итоге он не реагирует на нажатие как надо, а просто выводит имя.

Этот кусок кода оказывается работал, но только по нажатию имени, который указывается сверху маркера при его нажатии, мне же требовалось немного другое.
В итоге реализовал вот так:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(name));

            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), " has been clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Теперь он срабатывает именно на клики по маркеру.

А чтобы открыть из фрагмента новую активность, просто прописываем:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), InfoActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете в вашей View имплементировать интерфейс OnMarkerClickListener и в методе onMarkerClick вызывать вашу активити/фрагмент.

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMarkerClickListener{

    //Some code

    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker){
        Toast.makeText(this,  marker.getTitle() + " has been clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Соответственно при создании маркера методом addMarker вы получаете объект маркера и можете задавать ему теги или хранить сами маркеры и в зависимости от этих параметров в методе onMarkerClick выполнять разные действия.

Вот тут можно прочитать больше
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker